# Disallow dynamic URLs with @nuxtjs/robots module

Tags: nuxt.js

I have the following folder structure:

```
/pages/user/_user
```

And my current robots object in nuxt.config

```
robots: {
 UserAgent: '*',
 Disallow: '/user',
 Sitemap: 
 'https://www.misite.com/sitemap.xml'
},
```

I haven't found anything related in the module's docummentation so I was wondering how can I **disallow** the /_user URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible with robots module but don't forget you can add noindex tag to users pages.

```
<script>
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      meta: [
        { hid: 'robots', name: 'robots', content: 'noindex' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do know that I can add noindex but I also need o disallow the page but couldn't find anything related

Comment: Why not just Disallow: /user/*

Comment: Didn't know that it could be done. Will try! Thank you :)

Comment: I can confirm that this is the correct way, I've also asked one of the collaborators. Thank you!